# css animation change color

Tags: html, jquery, css

I built a "sticky header" with html, jquery and css animation
All works fine. But one little thing doesn't work correctly.

For the case, that the stick header will be active, the background color of the menu switch from white to green (with animation).

Now I need a function, which switch the color back from green to white (with animation), if the header is no sticky anymore (=class sticky will remove).

How can I realize this?

```js
var sticky = $("#header").offset().top
 
    $(window).scroll( function() {
        
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > sticky) {
            $("#header").addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $("#header").removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
```

```css
body {
        height: 5000px;
        background-color: #000;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
    #header {
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 50px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    
    .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      background-color: #7ebd0b !important;
      animation: switchColorToGreen .5s;
    }
    
    
    .sticky + .pageContainer {
      padding-top: 130px;
    }
    
    
    @keyframes switchColorToGreen {
      from {background-color: #fff;}
      to {background-color: #7ebd0b;}
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

    <header id="header">
        Menu 1           
    </header>
    


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is already working as expected.

Comment: Yes and no. The color will switch back from green to white, but without animation. I need an animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the code snippet in your question it's working fine. Is there anything different on the actual site you want to use this?

EDIT:
You could try this:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #7ebd0b !important;
}


 #header {
  background: white;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}
```

You don't even need the keyframes like this.
You need to put the transition on something that stay on the element all the time so it can control the transition.

Comment: Yes and no. The color will switch back from green to white, but without animation. I need an animation

Comment: Check my edit. That solution works for me.